# Set Value To Custom Field While Submit

Tags: custom-field, posting

Is it possible to set an automatic value to a custom field while submitting the post in wordpress?

When I post I need that this custom field take automatically the first letter of the post title.

Example: If my title is "Example" The custom field value is "E".

Comment: How are you adding the custom field, are you using a plugin?

Comment: no i write the post normally, the custom field is a default one of my theme.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by 'default one of my theme'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. If you're adding a custom field by a meta box you could do like this:

```
// add action to create your custom field
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'create_meta_box'  );
// add a callback that will be called when saving the post
add_filter( 'save_post', 'save_meta_box', 10, 2 );

// function that will create a meta box
function create_meta_box() {
   add_meta_box('sample_meta_box', __('Sample Box'), 'display_meta_box');     
}

// function that will display the actual meta box
function display_meta_box($post, $metabox) {
  ?>
   <input name="sample" type="text" id="sample" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sample', true); ?>">
  <?php
}

// function that will be called when the post is saved
function save_meta_box($post_id, $post) {
   // default value for the field
   $value = $_POST['post_title'][0];
   // only use the default value if user haven't specified one
   if(!empty($_POST['sample'])) {
      $value = $_POST['sample'];
   }
   // update the meta data for the post
   update_post_meta($post_id, 'sample', $value);
}
```

Of course you will have to change `sample` in this case to the name of your meta data field.

If you already have created a custom field through the administration interface, you could do like this:

```
// add a callback that will be called when saving the post
add_filter( 'save_post', 'save_custom_field', 10, 2 ); 

// called when updating a post
function save_custom_field($post_id, $post) {
   // loop through the meta data
   if(isset($_POST['meta'])) {
     foreach($_POST['meta'] as $key => $value) {
        // check if it's the correct field
        if($value['key'] == 'sample') {
           // this will always set the custom field to the first letter in the title
           update_post_meta($post_id, 'sample', $_POST['post_title'][0]);
           break;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Like in the first example you will have to change the `sample` to the name of your custom field.

Comment: but as "default value" i need the first letter of the post title.

Comment: I'm not showing a complete solution just pointing you in the right direction. I modify my code so the it will use the first letter of the title.

Comment: Really Thanks :) it's possible to do the same with custom taxonomy?

Comment: @user1825932 - If this answer helped you consider accept it and perhaps upvote=) And yes I think it would be possible but that is a different question.

Comment: I can't upvote, require 15 rep
I have to open another question for custom taxonomy?